# Read Max of years and months in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

In `Qlikview`, How can we display just the max of year and display the 2 max of Month, in table chart, but let the other years and months if the user want scroll it. Is it possible? like this :

[image: Here]

Thank you very much
Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a "Show All Months" Yes/No field in your load and place it above the chart. Then, when your user selects "Yes", an IF statement in the expression could change the set analysis used by the chart to alter how many months are displayed.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean! I have already my variable month and year. your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try [this](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-9250) sample QVW to see if that helps you clear up confusion. I think that what you're doing seems like a typical "Rolling N Months" set filter.

Comment: If the case is to control the scroll possibtion the answer is "you cant". You can't control the scrolls in QV/QS. One way to do is as @fchukoskie suggested - mark the max 2 months in your data and then just switch between yes/no in this field. If you want it more dynamic you can use set analysis for show only the last  2 months available or snow all months where the user can scroll. I'll try to make some app over the weekend and will share it here.

Comment: I've made a small example to show you https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjGsOE_3VoOQWFpY3NTbm5ZaU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.